# A few questions about Markov chains

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, markov-chains

> Let $\{X_n\}$, $n \geq 0$ be a Markov chain with the transition matrix $P$ such that
> $$
> \begin{array}{c|ccc}
>   &A &B &C \\
> \hline
> A &0.2 & 0.2 &0.6\\
> B &0 & 0.25 &0.75\\
> C &0.3 & 0.3 & 0.4
> \end{array}.
> $$

> a) How to find all the stationary distributions?

> b) If the Markov Chain starts in state $A$, what is the expected number of steps before it returns to $A$?

> c) How many times, on average, does the Markov Chain visit state $B$ between two visits to $A$.

I'm finding this topic quite tricky, so I really appreciate the help you guys are giving me :) I'd love if someone could explain all the steps to me.. :)

Comment: These problems are very fundamental in Markov Chains, I think you can find the methods in the textbook. For example, *Markov Chains with stationary transition probability(K.L.Chung)*

Comment: @Swayy Which textbook(s) are you using?

Comment: @Did Introduction to Probability, Grinstead

Comment: Surely the author explains how to find the stationary distribution(s) of a Markov chain on 3 states from its transition matrix, no?

Comment: @Did some of the explanations in the book are not very easy to follow (or maybe I'm just having trouble grasping it), which is why I was asking here for this problem. I was hoping someone could show me by example.

Comment: Are you telling me there is no worked-out example of finding the stationary distribution of a finite Markov chain?

Comment: @Did I had another comb through just to make sure there and I cannot find any examples on stationary distributions in the book. :/

Comment: *Introduction to Probability*, by Grinstead and Snell? Try section 11.3 *Ergodic Markov chains*. The theory is in Theorem 11.8, the practice begins with Exemple 11.19 and continues with many other exemples afterwards.

Comment: @Did found it! Thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize a discussion in the comments, the OP uses as a textbook *Introduction to Probability*, by Grinstead and Snell. The authors explain how to find the stationary distribution(s) of a Markov chain on a finite number of states from its transition matrix. Section 11.3 *Ergodic Markov chains* gives the theory in Theorem 11.8, and explains the practice starting at Example 11.19 and continuing with many other examples afterwards.